# Insert Fail because of wrong non-numeric character

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01858

hy

table:

```
create table Players (PlayerNo number (4) not null, Name varchar2(15), date_of_birth date,leagno varchar(4));
```

wrong insert:

```
insert into PLAYERS (PlayerNo,Name,date_of_birth,leagno) VALUES (1,'Philipp K','Jan-10-1999','1')
```

whats wrong?

error code:

```
Fehler beim Start in Zeile 1 in Befehl:
insert into PLAYERS (PlayerNo,Name,date_of_birth,leagno) VALUES (1,'Philipp K','Jan-10-1999','1')
Fehlerbericht:
SQL-Fehler: ORA-01858: Ein nicht-numerisches Zeichen wurde gefunden, während ein numerisches Zeichen erwartet wurde
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model
>   was
>              incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a
>   number was
>              required by the format model.

The date string you're using doesn't match what oracle is expecting.  The default format, iirc, is DD-Mon-YYYY, not Mon-DD-YYYY as you're trying to use.

Comment: The date format can be changed by the client, there really is no "default".  You should always use a TO_DATE like the other answers suggest.

Comment: The fact that it is settable without calling `TO_DATE` explicitly means that yes, there is a default format.  But, yes, calling `TO_DATE` is much more robust.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT
INTO PLAYERS
  (
    PlayerNo,
    Name,
    date_of_birth,
    leagno
  )
  VALUES
  (
    1,
    'Philipp K',
    TO_DATE('Jan-10-1999','Mon-dd-yyyy'),
    '1'
  )
```

You need to supply date using TO_DATE with the right format.

Answer (score 1):

The error explains:

> "The input data to be converted using
>   a date format model was  incorrect. 
>   The input data did not contain a
>   number where a number was required by
>   the format model"

What this means is the value you are passing to the date_of_birth column is in the wrong format.  By default Oracle expects dates to be in the format DD-MON-YYYY.  You are passing a date in the format MON-DD-YYYY.

There are two - well three - ways of dealing with this.

1. Use an explicit format mask: `to_date('Jan-10-1999', 'MON-DD-YYYY')`
2. change [the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm), at the session or even database level.  F[ind out more here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2012.htm#SQLRF00901)  and [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2013.htm#i2154767).
3. change your insert statement to pass the date in the expected format.